# Formik renders twice on initialization

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have this simple example of Formik where i have a simple input. When i run the page i see in the console that it renders twice. The formik package is exactly the same as the first message.
Why it renders twice if there is nothing changed?

```
 const SignupForm = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
  });
 

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={data}
      enableReinitialize
      validateOnBlur={false}
      validateOnChange={false}
      onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
      }}
    >
      {(formik) => {
        console.log(formik);

        return (
          <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
            <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
            <input
              id="firstName"
              type="text"
              {...formik.getFieldProps("firstName")}
            />
            {formik.touched.firstName && formik.errors.firstName ? (
              <div>{formik.errors.firstName}</div>
            ) : null}
            
          </form>
        );
      }}
    </Formik>
  );
};
```

Comment: Is react strict mode enabled?

Comment: @SergeySosunov No i checked it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is happening due to `enableReinitialize` property.

Formik itself has a few `useEffect`s inside of it, and a `formikReducer`. So when you pass `enableReinitialize` - formikReducer is called 2 times:

```
payload: {}, type: "SET_ERRORS"
payload: {}, type: "SET_TOUCHED"
```

Which is happening due to folowing useEffects inside of the source codes:

```
React.useEffect(function () {
  if (enableReinitialize && isMounted.current === true && !isEqual(initialErrors.current, props.initialErrors)) {
    initialErrors.current = props.initialErrors || emptyErrors;
    dispatch({
      type: 'SET_ERRORS',
      payload: props.initialErrors || emptyErrors
    });
  }
}, [enableReinitialize, props.initialErrors]);
React.useEffect(function () {
  if (enableReinitialize && isMounted.current === true && !isEqual(initialTouched.current, props.initialTouched)) {
    initialTouched.current = props.initialTouched || emptyTouched;
    dispatch({
      type: 'SET_TOUCHED',
      payload: props.initialTouched || emptyTouched
    });
  }
}, [enableReinitialize, props.initialTouched]);
```

And those `if`s are passed due to the `initialTouched` and `initialErrors` are initialized inside of the Formik with this:

```
var initialErrors = React.useRef(props.initialErrors || emptyErrors);
var initialTouched = React.useRef(props.initialTouched || emptyTouched);
```

So `initial` values are equal to `empty` ones which are `{}`. But inside of the `if` they have `!isEqual(initialErrors.current, props.initialErrors))` for example, so comparison between `{}` and `undefined` is passed and we are going inside of the `if` body and **updating the Formik internal state**. That is what is causing an additional rerender.

So if you pass the following props to Formik component - console.log will be executed only once

```
initialErrors={{}}
initialTouched={{}}
```

Now about how to collect that information:

1. Configure local minimal workspace with React and Formik
2. Go to `node_modules/formik/dist/formik.cjs.development.js` and inject some logging code inside of the `formikReducer`, simple console.log
3. In the component that is using `<Formik>` import it from modified development js file. `import { Formik } from "formik/dist/formik.cjs.development";`

Formik version: 2.2.9

Comment: This is an outstanding evaluation and should be filed as a "bug" with Formik.